# Using a Web Site Document with an XPage - how to setup correctly?

Tags: xpages

I have set up a small XPage and have until now used the full path to the Xpage for testing, i.e.

> http://devsrv1.magerman.ch/Development/Schulungen/Schulungen1_0/Schulungen_(1_0)_Dev.nsf/HomeWithDataView.xsp

I then tried to apply a Web Site Document
[image]
[image]

But the links are no longer currently functioning. I have the feeling that I'm missing something pretty basic, and am unsure as to what the best practice is. I'm quite happy with having the original request to the hostname resolve to a full path, i.e.

input

> schulungen.magerman.com

and have it resolve to

> schulungen.magerman.com//Development/Schulungen/Schulungen1_0/Schulungen_(1_0)_Dev.nsf

but haven't found a way to do this elegantly.

At the moment, my relative links '/OtherXpage.xsp' fail as they try to get to schulungen.magerman.com/OtherXpage.xsp

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

Create a **[Web Site Rule](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_WEB_SITE_RULES_OVERVIEW.html)**. You can create it from your Web Site document in edit mode with action button " Web Site ... / Create Rule".

You can find a description how to fill the fields [here](http://www.pmooney.net/2010/12/creating-a-url-redirection-for-a-domino-web-server/).

Comment: Knut, that looks like exactly the basic knowledge that I was needing. I'll try it out as soon as I'm back on my dev machine.

Comment: Knut, I can see where redirection might work if you are redirecting a subset of the site. But here all I am looking for is: user types in http://www.uklug.info  in the browser, and the url automcatically expands to http://www.uklug.info/iconuk/iconuk2014.nsf - at which point my links function correctly.

Comment: Knut, I'm having a similar problem on the same server. try typing http://snougdemo.magerman.com/ in your browser URL. It stays at http://snougdemo.magerman.com/, when I want it to expand to http://snougdemo.magerman.com/demo/snoug.nsf (with the Web Site Document) and then to http://snougdemo.magerman.com/demo/snoug.nsf/home.xsp (because of the launch database properties). But it sticks. I looked at similarly set up databases on the same server and their URLs were 'expanding', and they don't need the Web Site Rule, so I'm tempted to think that my problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is usually that you need to add a trailing slash to the hostname
http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2013/quicktip-get-right-path-when-autolaunching-an-xpage